# can ssis script component output an array

Tags: ssis

I have one row which contains 6 columns: id, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5

What I am trying to do:

for each id, do a sequence check: c1-c2, c2-c3, c3-c4, c4-c5, and for any pair which does not equal each other, assign an extra flag to indicate.

I am trying to use script in ssis:

create an array c[] = {c1,c2,c3,c4,c5} and an array flag[]

```
 for(i=1,if<=4,i++)
        for(j=i+1,j<=5,j++)
            if c[i] != c[j]
                Flag[i] = 1
```

in this way, there would be 4 flag to output against c1,c2,c3,c4 for 1 id, whcih change the granular

could I do that?

SPSS can do this definitely like this

STRING flag (A1)

EXECUTE.

VECTOR c=c1 TO c5.

LOOP #i=1 TO 4.

LOOP #a=(#i + 1) TO 5.

- DO IF c(#a) != c(#i)
- COMPUTE flag=1.
- BREAK.
- END IF.
- END LOOP.

END LOOP.

EXECUTE.

Comment: Why not do it in the SQL that generates the row?

Comment: thanks, I prefer using loop in SQL instead of a branch of UNION ALL, any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I would generate the four flag columns in SQL with CASE Statements:

```
CASE c1 = c2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Flag1
CASE c2 = c3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Flag2
```

and so on.

Comment: i have over 100 columns to compare, then having 100+ flags is abit annoying :)